# Как запускать web-socket сервер автоматически через консоль?

Tags: php, apache, websocket, консоль, ratchet

сделал web-socket сервер на сайте с помощью Ratchet php. Запускаю сервер вручную через консоль . но , как понимаю , не вариант каждый раз запускать процесс через консоль . Надо чтобы сервер запускался автоматически при загрузке сайта и работал себе автономно . По информации из сети , слышал , что для таких целей нужно использывать сетевых демонов . Верно ли ?

Comment: Вам надо просто добавить запуск вашего сервера в скрипты автозагрузке. смотреть что нибудь вроде /etc/local.d в разных системах загрзука немного в разных местах расположена

Comment: можно немножко поподробнее ? перерыл кучу информации , но ничего толкового не нашел

Comment: У вас каталог /etc/local.d есть ? Если да - кладете туда файл в который пишите команду запуска. Имейте ввиду в момент его работы могут быть еще не прописаны пути к основным папкам, поэтому все команды надо писать с полными путями. Возможно там файл какой нибудь уже есть - можно в него дописать

Comment: Если каталоге нет, изучать содержимое /etc/init.d и /etc/rc.d там все файлы автозапуска, только с ними поаккуратнее, они все таки всю систему запускают. Там наверняка есть какой нибудь файл local который откуда нибудь стартует пользовательские скрипты. надо в нем разобраться откуда стартует и туда положить или в него самого

Comment: Смотрите , у меня установлен Apache . нету там каталогов этих

Comment: Апач тут не причем. какой то из этих каталогов есть в любой unix системе. еще каталог rc.d может быть  разбит на несколько, тогда нам интересны rc3.d или rc5.d

Comment: но  подождите , я , кажеться , не шарю нечего . Сейчас мой сайт на локальном сервере , но когда я его выложу на реальный хостинг , как тогда запускать этот сервер с  сокетами

Comment: Хм. А вот это уже надо будет выяснять у хостера, в принипе они должны предоставлять такие возможности

Comment: ну ладно , спасибо тогда и на этом

Comment: Я бы конечно предложил что бы этот скрипт писал в какой нибудь файл свой pid, а первое же обращение к сайту (через обычный апачевкский php) проверяло запущен ли соответствующий процесс и если нет - то что бы запускало в фоне. Это возможно, но опять же могут быть ограничения хостера на подобные функции или на время выполнения скриптов